# Do we need [gadgets]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

The [gadget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gadget) and [gadgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gadgets) tags suffer from :

- Ambiguity (there are windows-live-gadget, google-gadget, wso2gadgets..)
- Not being really useful at all.
- Not having a lot of questions

So should we destroy these?

Comment: Since apparently users with no full-editing priviledge should not edit out tags, I'd appreciate someone helping me out!

Comment: This was asked a year ago @Veve

Comment: I know, I've duplicated this because the linked question has now a definitive answer, it seems more logical this way than the other way around.