# How much gadgetry does SO need in its tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request, tag-synonym-process

I was reviewing (and rejecting) a proposed change to the question [What's the "gadget vulnerability"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11490844/whats-the-gadget-vulnerability) which added the tag [windows-gadgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-gadgets) to the existing duo of [windows-desktop-gadgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-desktop-gadgets) and [gadget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gadget), and there's also a plural [gadgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gadgets).

Looking at the raw statistics:

- [gadget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gadget) has no wiki description, 178 questions, no top answerer with more than 1 answer, and minimal activity in the last 30 days.
- <s>[windows-gadgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-gadgets) has a wiki description, 19 questions, one top answerer with 3 answers, everyone else with one, and minimal recent activity.</s> *All questions previously tagged [windows-gadgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-gadgets) are now tagged [windows-desktop-gadgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-desktop-gadgets).*
- [windows-desktop-gadgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-desktop-gadgets) has a wiki description, 190 questions, some answerers with significant activity (one person has answered 36 questions!), but minimal recent activity.
- <s>[gadgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gadgets) has no tag wiki, 27 questions, one answerer with 3 answers (everyone else just one) and minimal recent activity.</s> The questions previously tagged [gadgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gadgets) have been detagged or retagged (sometimes [windows-desktop-gadgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-desktop-gadgets), sometimes [google-gadget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-gadget)).

The descriptions of [windows-gadgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-gadgets) and [windows-desktop-gadgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-desktop-gadgets) makes it clear they're describing the same thing.

A scanty survey of the [gadget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gadget) and [gadgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gadgets) tags suggests that the term is used in other contexts than just Windows Desktop Gadgets.  Any retagging needs to be done carefully.

#### Suggested fix-ups

1. <s>Synonymize [windows-gadgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-gadgets) and [windows-desktop-gadgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-desktop-gadgets) using the longer name as the canonical form.</s> *No longer necessary.*
2. <s>Synonmize [gadget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gadget) and [gadgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gadgets) (using [gadget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gadget) as the canonical tag since it has by far the larger number of questions) unless both are burninated.  Maybe a quick improvement is to synonymize these two before they're eliminated — by retagging to [windows-desktop-gadgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-desktop-gadgets) when that's appropriate or by removing the gadgetry tag when it is not.</s> *No longer necessary.*

Retagging the [windows-gadgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-gadgets) questions as [windows-desktop-gadgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-desktop-gadgets) <s>is</s> was doable manually.

Retagging (and detagging) the [gadgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gadgets) questions <s>as [gadget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gadget) is</s> was also doable manually.

Cleaning up the [gadget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gadget) list <s>will probably be</s> was fiddly.

For some reason, the question [Do we need [gadgets]?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294235/do-we-need-gadgets) escaped everyone's attention when I opened this question.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Suggested title: Go-go [gadget] tags

Comment: The most accurate definition for "gadget" that I know is "a small thing that does something". Unless someone can give a more firm definition, I say we burninate `[gadget]` and `[gadgets]` (retagging to `[windows-gadgets]` if appropriate).

Comment: @Siguza: Use tag [tag:windows-desktop-gadgets] rather than [tag:windows-gadgets] in the relabelling, and I'm on board with your suggestion.

Comment: windows-gadgets makes more sense

Comment: @OblongMedulla: too late; the clean up has removed [tag:windows-gadgets] completely (and [tag:gadgets] too).  Unless you're into masochism, the name going forward is Windows Desktop Gadgets.  The [tag:gadget] tag still needs careful work.  There are sundry other tags that may be relevant to retag with, or removing the tag may be best.

Comment: Hey that works too! You guys work fast around here!

Comment: I'm upvoting this purely for the reason that you didn't try to come up with a terrible punny title, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Summary

- [gadgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gadgets) has been eliminated.
- [gadget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gadget) has been eliminated.
- [windows-gadgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-gadgets) has been eliminated.

Trogdor was here!

[image: This tag has been burninated]